# What is the best way, in Angular 2, to make a map with clickable country boundaries in Google Maps?

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, leaflet

I am using the Google Maps api to create a simple map, where the country borders will highlight on mouseover, and will have the ability have a click event.

I have looked at the Google maps Fusion tables, and various questions on Stack Overflow, but have not found a good solution that works well for Angular 2.

The Angular 2 google maps documentation seems pretty incomplete, so it seems like using the vanilla google maps docs in an Angular 2 context might be better.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

There are good Angular2 integrations of Leaflet.js that would fulfill your needs (adding a layer for country boundaries in geojson at the desired detail level).

Comment: Leaflet look awesome.  I had no idea about it.  Great resource - thanks a lot